# Can a GCP custom route point to a destination URL (as opposed to an IP range)?

Tags: networking, nat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine

**Objective**

I need to access an external API (say, www.api.com) from an App Engine app. The external API requires source IP whitelisting.

**Problem**

App Engine does not allow me to reserve external IP addresses.

**Attempted solution**

I plan to use a NAT gateway, but only for requests that are sent to api.com.

My plan:

1. Create a GCE VM, configured as a NAT gateway (don't care about High Availability at the moment; can add that in later). Described [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#natgateway).
2. Create a custom Route that specifies the destination URL (*not* an IP range!)

**Problem with solution**

I am not sure if #2 above is possible: I can specify a destination IP range, but not a URL. One solution is to route *all* external traffic through the NAT gateway, but that seems unnecessary, and might force me to think about a high-availability NAT gateway sooner than is needed.

**Question**

Is there a way I can achieve my goal by specifying a destination URL? Or is that simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usual solution would require the use of a proxy, by your app. Proxy enables IP white-listing. You may find related information in replies to the [Whitelisting an application hosted in google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376044/whitelisting-an-application-hosted-in-google-app-engine) question, as well as ['Google App Engine does not support the use of proxies' error when connecting to Google Compute Engine proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493844/google-app-engine-does-not-support-the-use-of-proxies-error-when-connecting-to).